# Is there a way to use a custom css file(!) for one specific divi module?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Hei,

I need to implement CSS for a code module (divi) and the "Custom CSS field" of divi can't handle the sum of lines which I have to add. So is there maybe a way to tell this divi module to get some CSS from a specific file? Maybe with the "@include"?

I appreciate every suggestion that might help me, so thank you very much in advance.

P.S.
The CSS file has 10k lines.

Comment: Does your divi module appear on every pages or only on specific ones? Do you have access to your theme's files?

Comment: It appears only on one Site and yes I have full access to all files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As easy fix you could try to minify your css file with some tool like this: https://cssminifier.com/.

Second solution would be a custom css file in your child-theme. After creating you can enqueue you custom css file in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles () {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'divi-module-custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '<path to custom css file(/css/custom-divi.css)>', array(), '1.0.0' );

    }
}
```

Comment: The minified version works :) thanks for your input